# Linux kernel hacking the open system call for Linux 4.6.x

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to replace the linux system call for the open function with my own function. Sys_call_table sysmbol is not exported after kernel versions 2.6. I hardcode the virtual address of the sys_call_table from the system.map file.

I save the original system call [ NR_OPEN] and then try to use the set_memory_rw function from the system_map as it is not available for arm linux. I am writing the kernel module for beaglebone. If I try to use the function using the virtual address given in system.map file via function pointers, I get Kernel oops that unable to handle kernel paging request.

System_call_table is read only, if I try to write to it it gives kernel oops at the str instruction.

I am using the following code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <asm/memory.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");              ///< The license type -- this
affects runtime behavior MODULE_AUTHOR("Zohaib");      ///< The author
-- visible when you use modinfo


unsigned long *sys_call_table = (unsigned long *) 0xc0107a28;  int a;
unsigned long phy_addr_sys_call_table,x;

asmlinkage unsigned long int (*vir_to_phy) (unsigned long int x);
static asmlinkage int (*set_mem_rw) (unsigned long int, int); static
asmlinkage int (**write) (unsigned long int, int); static asmlinkage
int (*original_call) (const char*, int, int); int ret;

static asmlinkage int our_sys_open(const char* file, int flags, int
mode) {    printk("A file was opened\n");    return
original_call(file, flags, mode); }

static int __init hello_module(void) {
    // sys_call_table address in System.map

    printk("NEW \n");
    x= virt_to_phys((void*)0xc0115fe0);
    printk(" %p", (void*)(x));
    printk(" \n \n \n DEBUG POINT 1:");
    write=(int (**) (unsigned long int, int))(virt_to_phys((void*)0xc0115fe0));


    printk("\n \n \n DEBUG POINT 2");
    set_mem_rw= *write;


    printk("HI \n");
    printk(" \n \n \n : %p", set_mem_rw);

    a=__NR_open;
    printk(" \n \n \n %i",a);

    original_call = (void*)*(sys_call_table + __NR_open);
    printk("\n \n \n vir_to_phys test \n");

    phy_addr_sys_call_table= virt_to_phys((void*)0xc0107a28);
    printk("\n \n \n vir_to_phys test succeeded: %p", (void*)phy_addr_sys_call_table);

    printk("\n CRASHINNNNNNNNN..... ");
    // this is where it crashes.
    ret=(*set_mem_rw)((unsigned long)phy_addr_sys_call_table,20);

    printk("\n CRASH point no.1 ");

    printk( "\n %lu ", sys_call_table[__NR_open]);
    printk( "\n %p ", original_call);
    printk(" \n DIDN'T CRASH at point no.1 \n");

    printk("CRASH point no.2 \n");

    printk("%p", sys_call_table);
    printk(" \n DIDN'T CRASH at point no.2 \n");


    // read only sys_call_table, cannot write to it if readwrite privilege is not given, gives kernel oops otherwise
    printk(" \n \n %p \n", (our_sys_open));
    *(sys_call_table + __NR_open) = (unsigned long)our_sys_open;

    printk(" \n SUCCEEDED ");

    return 0; }

static void __exit bye_module(void) {    // Restore the original call
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = original_call;

    printk("BYE"); }

module_init(hello_module); module_exit(bye_module);
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to hook a system call in the first place? The kernel was designed specifically to discourage this around 2.6.

Comment: This is just for learning purposes.

Comment: I want to know how to use functions from the virtual addresses that are given in the system.map file.

Comment: I think the problem is in the function access via the virtual address.

Comment: `I want to know how to use functions from the virtual addresses that are given in the system.map file.` - Simply call them. Kernel code operates with virtual addresses too, no needs in `virt_to_phys` translations. The same for operands of `set_memory_wr`: they are virtual addresses, not physical.

Comment: @Tsyvarev But if I use the virtual address and call the set_memory_rw function with it, it gives kernel oops. the function set_memory_rw doesn't work by using the virtual address.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sys_call_table is read only, in order to change its mode to read write, will I have to give its virtual address or physical address?

Comment: `set_memory_rw` operates with *pages*, it can be obtained by right shifting (virtual) address by *PAGE_OFFSET*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev can set_memory_rw be used to set sys call table rw from ro? I have read that it cannot set sys call table rw because of static protection? what other function can I use?

Comment: `I have read that it cannot set sys call table rw because of static protection?` - First time hear about that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have used set_memory_rw( virtual_address, no.of.pages), the return value is negative, hence an error during the execution of the function.

Comment: `I have used set_memory_rw( virtual_address, no.of.pages)` - It should be `set_memory_rw(virtual_address >> PAGE_OFFSET, no-of-pages)`. If this doesn't help, [edit] your question and show your attempt when you call the function in that way.